# How to bind data of instance of object A to corresponding instance of object B?

Tags: python, oop

I'm writing another "bicycle" for reading .ini files to get some experience in advanced Python and OOP. Also I find default Python's configparser access style a little unpleasant for eyes, i.e.: `something = config['section']['parameter']` instead of more eye-candish `something = config.section.parameter`.

I've ended up with this design:

- `ConfigStorage` object to keep pairs of parameter/value as dictionary;
- `Config` object to manage data in storage object.

`__getattribute__` in `Config` object is overridden so I can access values in `ConfigStorage` dictionary by attribute name of `Config` object (*the goal!*).

The system works OK when there is only one instance of `Config` object. When I tried to work with multiple configs (and, therefore, instantiate new `Config` objects to manage them), I realized that `ConfigStorage` is *one for all*.

I've tried to create new instance of `ConfigStorage` for every `Config` object but Python reaches maximum recursion depth in this code (*why?*):

```py
class _ConfigStorage(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = dict()


class Config(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in self.c.config:
            return self.c.config[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("No parameter named [%s]" % name)

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.c = _ConfigStorage()
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            for config_line in f:
                key = # getting key from line
                value = # getting value
                self.c.config[key] = value
```

Finally, I got my code working, but I find this solution very crude and tainted with black magic. I separate data in storage object by adding to dictionary key a string representation of `Config` object ID. The `ConfigStorage` object is still single.
Also `__del__` method is needed, as GC don't know about unnecessary data in storage and I have to remove them manually. It sucks.

```py
class _ConfigStorage(object):
    config = dict()


class Config(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        key = str(id(self)) + name
        if key in _ConfigStorage.config:
            return _ConfigStorage.config[key]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("No parameter named [%s]" % name)

    def __init__(self, file):
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            for config_line in f:
                key = str(id(self) + # getting key from line
                value = # getting value
                _ConfigStorage.config[key] = value

    def __del__(self):
        instance_id = str(id(self))
        keys_to_delete = []
        for key in _ConfigStorage.config:
            if instance_id in key:
                keys_to_delete.append(key)
        for key_to_delete in keys_to_delete:
            del _ConfigStorage.config[key_to_delete]
```

How can I improve the design, being able to access dictionary data by object attribute?

Comment: Why do you introduce a `_ConfigStorage` class which contains nothing but a dictionary, if you can just use a dictionary?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you use this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 just exploring: writing my own implementation of configparser. Learning from reinventing bicycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this implementation suits your needs:

```
class Config(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self.config:
            return self.config[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("No parameter named [%s]" % name)

    def __init__(self, file=None):
        # changed to make it work without real file
        self.config = {'key': 'value'}

config = Config()
print(config.key)  # value
print(config.not_a_key)  # AttributeError: ...
```

No need to write `_ConfigStorage` and `__del__`, no infinite recursion, access by dot notation.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. Now have to learn difference between `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`.

Comment: Here is a good point to start https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access

Answer (score 0):

Silly, but I found more elegant way to solve my problem.

```py
class Config(object):
    config = dict()

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in Config.config:
            return Config.config[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("No parameter named [%s]" % name)

    def __init__(self, file):
        try:
            with open(file, 'r') as f:
                for config_line in f:
                    config_line = config_line.strip()
                    eq_position = config_line.find('=')
                    key = config_line[:eq_position].strip()
                    value = config_line[eq_position + 1:].strip()
                    Config.config[key] = value
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('File not found')
```

Comment: Having `config` as a class variable, you still need to collect garbage from already unused configs manually.

Comment: Oh. Didn't thought about it. Thank you!